# Cordova plugin with remote url works well with iOS but not Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to load a website with its URL in a Cordova WebView in my Cordova project.

This works fine (the site is loaded)

I developed a custom Cordova plugin, the javascript part is remote and it works well with my iOS project, but not with my Android project.

The Android (Java) part of the plugin is not hit.

Here is the code I added to config.xml:

```
<feature name="HybridBridge">
    <param name="android-package" value="HybridBridge"/>
</feature>
```

The code of the Java part of the plugin:

```
public class HybridBridge extends CordovaPlugin {
    public static final String ACTION_ADD_CALENDAR_ENTRY = "triggerAction";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        try {
            if (ACTION_ADD_CALENDAR_ENTRY.equals(action)) { 
               JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
               // Do something
               callbackContext.success();
               return true;
            }
            callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
            return false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint just before try and its never reached.

Code of the javascript:

```
var HybridBridge = {
    createEvent: function(title) {
        cordova.exec(
            successCallback, // success callback function
            errorCallback, // error callback function
            'HybridBridge', // mapped to our native Java class called "CalendarPlugin"
            'triggerAction', // with this action name
            [{                  // and this array of custom arguments to create our entry
                "some arguments": title,
            }]
        ); 
    }
}
```

Tell me if you need any more code.

Comment: In your js code, you are calling to _addCalendarEntry_ action, while on the native plugin you are comparing if action equals _triggerAction_

Comment: Oh yes this was the local plugin code sorry, in the remote site it is actually triggerAction.